# How to write an app layout in Dash such that two graphs are side by side?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to plot two charts side by side (and not one above the other) in Dash by Plotly. 
The tutorials did not have an example where the graphs are plotted side by side.

I am writing the `app.layout` in the following way

```
app.layout = html.Div(className = 'row', children=

    [
        html.H1("Tips database analysis (First dashboard)"),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='d',
                     options = col_options,
                    value = 'Sun'),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph1"),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph2")
    ]

)
```

but after this `graph1` appears above `graph2` rather than side by side

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping the graphs in a `div` and adding `display: inline-block` css property to each of the graphs.

```py
app.layout = html.Div(className='row', children=[
    html.H1("Tips database analysis (First dashboard)"),
    dcc.Dropdown(),
    html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(id="graph1", style={'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph2", style={'display': 'inline-block'})
    ])
])
```

Result[image: Side-by-side Graphs]

**EDIT**

I removed the `display: flex` property from the wrapping div, and instead added the `display: inline-block` property to each of the graphs. This makes it so the second graph does not get cut off, and will instead stack on smaller screens.

Comment: That does work thanks!, however this way doesn't let graphs occupy the full space on the screen as I still have some space on the right side of the screen, any idea how to correct that so that graphs use all the available space?

Comment: When I inspect the graph elements in my browser, I'm unable to see any padding/margin around them, so I think those margins are just baked into the graphs by plotly. Unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to remove those. Maybe post another question regarding that issue

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I am curious whether it is possible to make the widths of graphs the same and auto-adjusted based on the screen width?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case someone wants to use a horizontal spacer between the plots, so that the space in the middle is filled by the spacer and the plots are positioned on the outer left and outer right side - the following approach is successful in my case.

**Step 1:**

Add an **assets** folder to the root folder of your project. This asset folder is allowed to contain .css and .js files. This allows one to add custom css to a dash app, as stated here: [https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources#:~:text=Adding%20Your%20Own%20CSS%20and%20JavaScript%20to%20Dash%20Apps&text=Including%20custom%20CSS%20or%20JavaScript,are%20included%20in%20this%20folder](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources#:%7E:text=Adding%20Your%20Own%20CSS%20and%20JavaScript%20to%20Dash%20Apps&text=Including%20custom%20CSS%20or%20JavaScript,are%20included%20in%20this%20folder).

**Step 2:**

Add the **style.css** file to your **assets** folder, containing the following css:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.plot{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .parent{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .plot{
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

The dash project locates the .css file automatically, as long as it is stored in the **assets** folder.

**Step 3:**

Wrap your plots with a `html.Div()` and put another `html.Div()` between the plots. Set the `className` parameter of both `html.Div()`'s and the `dcc.Graph()`'s according to the css classes which were defined in the **style.css** file

```
 app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(className='row', children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(),
        html.Div(className='parent', children=[
            dcc.Graph(id='plot1', className='plot'),
            html.Div(className='spacer'),
            dcc.Graph(id='plot2', className='plot'),
        ])
    ]),
])
```

**Edit:**

Added media query and some additional styles to the css, now it can also be used as a responsive solution